# MySQL add Foreign Key

Tags: mysql, key

I want to update a column which is currently a plain INT(16) so that it references a FK on another table. I've tried the following, but with errors:

```
ALTER TABLE ts_keys ADD CONSTRAINT FK_account_id FOREIGN KEY (account_id) REFERENCES accounts(id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
```

EDIT: Sorry, forgot to add the error:

```
Can't create table (errno: 150)
```

Both tables are Innodb.

EDIT 2: I also tried re-creating the table but same error:

```
    CREATE TABLE ts_keys (
  id int PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  account_id int,
  FOREIGN KEY fk_account_id1(account_id) REFERENCES accounts(id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Comment: Did you get errors? What errors?

Comment: The first one is just incorrect syntax, check the MySQL manual. `MODIFY columnname` has to be followed by a column definition, not a foreign key definition. For the second error, there are many other questions here that explain what causes error 150. There are a number of possible causes, and you haven't provided enough information to know what it is. So do a search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The datatype of the foreign key column must match *EXACTLY* the datatype of the referenced column.

Do a `SHOW CREATE TABLE accounts` and look at the definition of the `id` column.

Whatever that column is defined as `INT UNSIGNED`, `BIGINT`, `VARCHAR(16)`, whatever,

the column you want to define as a foreign key (the `account_id` column in `ts_keys` table) must match that datatype *EXACTLY*. (It's just the datatype that has to match. The column comment doesn't have to match, the DEFAULT value doesn't have to match, the NULL/NOT NULL doesn't have to match. But it's required that the datatypes match.

---

Your syntax for adding the constraint looks correct:

```
ALTER TABLE ts_keys
  ADD CONSTRAINT FK_account_id 
  FOREIGN KEY (account_id) 
  REFERENCES accounts(id) 
  ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
```

Admittedly, the "Can't create table (errno: 150)" has to be the *least* helpful message regarding what's actually causing the problem. (At least the error isn't the "check the manual" syntax error.